# Symfony 2 Doctrine ODM with reference

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

So I have two following documents:

**Wallpapers**

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(
 *    collection="wallpapers",
 *    repositoryClass="Application\Bundle\DefaultBundle\Repository\WallpaperRepository"
 * )
 */
class Wallpaper
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
     * @var string $id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(
     *     targetDocument="Category"
     * )
     *
     * 
     */
    private $categories;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**Categories:**

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="categories")
 */
class Category
{

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
     * @var string $id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="boolean")
     *
     * @var bool $published
     */
    private $published;
}
```

And I need select all wallpapers which contain only published categories...
I tried many solutions, which I found by Google search. But still not found solution for my problem...

Here my query:

```
$wallpapers = $this->createQueryBuilder('ApplicationDefaultBundle:Wallpaper')
            ->field('categories.published')->equals(true)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute()
```

But it doesn't work:(

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a relational DB you'll do that with a Join, however in mongodb you can either:

---

de-normalize your referenced category in your Wallpaper document:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Category")
 */
private $categories;
```

(notice the EmbedMany)

In this way your query will work (but the categories will be duplicated inside each Wallpaper)

---

Or do this simple trick (if the number of categories isn't too high):

```
//Get all the ids of the published categories:
$categories = $this->createQueryBuilder('ApplicationDefaultBundle:Category')
            ->field('published')->equals(true)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute()
$categoriesIds = array();
foreach($categories as $c) {
    $categoriesIds[] = $c->getId();
}

//Get the wallpapers for that categories:
$wallpapers = $this->createQueryBuilder('ApplicationDefaultBundle:Wallpaper')
            ->field('categories.$id')->in($categories)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute()
```

If the published categories are only 100-200 this trick is ok.

Comment: I would further optimize the category query by selecting only _id field and not hydrating the results. Just add `->fields(array('_id'))->hydrate(false)` to the first query builder and instead of `$c->getId()` use `$c['_id']`.